# Recover lost data from VirtualBox/Vagrant after host crash

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vdi, vmdk

Our linux server has been rebooted after server crash/freeze.

Trying to use a virtual machine (using vagrant up) , I've noticed the VM (created with vagrant) reverted to a prior version (version of the first week since vm creation).

I 'm now trying to recover the data (important data).

I've got the original files of the vm in "VirtualBox VMs folder" and the same files backuped on ftp server (the backup were created 1 day before crash) :

The Folders contain : 
 **- vm.vbox ,

- vm.vbox-prev ,
- vm.vmdk ,
- vm.vdi**

I  tried to mount  each of the "vm.vdi" ("qemu-nbd -c ...")(the backup "vm.vdi" and  the original one).
I then tried to clone the vm ("VBoxManage clonevm ...") and check for new files in the cloned vm , clone the vdis ("VBoxManage clonehd") and mount the cloned ones,  package the box and create a new vagrant box from the original one packaged , but nothing to do, the data has been reverted to the creation of the virtual machine.

In the past, we've shutdown the host and the vm many times without troubles (gracefull shutdown ).

**Host and VM :  ubuntu bionic 18.04 ,

Virtualbox  :  5.2.18 ,

Vagrant     :  2.0.3**

Any suggestions ?